# Hiding slideshow on click

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide a slideshow when a X button is clicked, but it is not working. I'm not sure if it has anything to do with the `"id"` or `"class"`, but I've tried everything already and it is not hiding what I want it to. (can't use Jquery, this is for a little school project). I usually can hide everything using that button and function, but I can't make it work with the slideshow.

```
<div id="slideshow-container">
  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

 <button id="exit" onclick="hideSlides(this, 'slideshow-container')">
  <img id="exit" src="image/exit.png">
 </button>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/remar1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/remar2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/remar3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/remar4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/remar5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/remar6.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/remar7.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/remar8.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/casa1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/casa2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/casa3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/casa4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/casa5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/casa6.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/casa7.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose1.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose2.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose3.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose4.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose5.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose6.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose7.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose8.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <img src="image/jose9.jpg" style="width:100%">
  </div>

  </div>


//javascript
  function hideSlides(){
  var slides = 
  document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides").style.display="none"

  }

//css
  .mySlides {
  display: none;
  visibility: visible;
  }
  img {vertical-align: middle;}


  #slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  height: 200px;
  left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  bottom: 1932px;
  visibility: hidden;
  }


 .prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;

  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`document.getElementsByClassName` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). So with your current `HTML` design, you have to iterate over all the selected elements and apply the style you want.

With ES6, you may use `Array.from` which builds arrays from array-like objects.
You can find the documentation of `Array.from` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)

So you can change your function like this:

```
function hideSlides(){
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(slides, function(el) {
        el.style.display = 'none';
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

is `hideSlides()` the function called when you click x? Try declaring the variable, then adding the style:

```
function hideSlides(){
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides")
    slides.style.display="none"  
}
```

And in case you want to get rid of the empty space where it was, you will need to change the visibility as well.

Comment: The function called was the right one, but it still wasn't working. That method still didn't work, but thank you anyway!